# Working with OpenCV Python, Microscopic Videos

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing

I have a slow performing Imshow when i used scikit framework, is it because of the following code?

```
while True:
    ret, frame = offlinevid.read()
    frame = cv2.resize(frame, size, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
    # Test Processing
    imgforprocessing = img_as_float(frame)
    sigma_est = np.mean(estimate_sigma(imgforprocessing, multichannel = True))
    nlm = denoise_nl_means(imgforprocessing, h = 1.5*sigma_est, fast_mode=True, patch_size = 5, patch_distance= 3, multichannel = True)
    #cv2.imshow("Test", nlm) 
    cv2.imshow("Test", frame)
```

I want to play like a normal 30fps video but when I put in the denoise_nl_means, it just drops to 5 frames per second. How can I improve it?

Edit: I should provide more info. When i removed the denoise_nl_means, the video play framerate is ack to normal. I want to use the denoise because I am working with microscopic images which has lots of noise. Is there an OpenCV function for me to do the same as denoise_nl_means?

I have tried Ridge Detection with Morphing

```
ridge_filter = cv2.ximgproc.RidgeDetectionFilter_create(cv2.CV_32FC1, 1, 1 , 3, cv2.CV_8UC1, 1, 0 , cv2.BORDER_DEFAULT)
    ridges = ridge_filter.getRidgeFilteredImage(frame)

    blank_mask = np.zeros(frame.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
    thresh = cv2.threshold(ridges, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
    kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (3,3))
    opening = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel, iterations=1)  

    inverse = 255 - opening
    inverse = cv2.merge([inverse,inverse,inverse])
    removed_artifacts = cv2.bitwise_and(frame,frame,mask=opening)
```

The removed_artifacts still have the noise from the microscopic images. 
This is just an example [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41ZF8.jpg)
and the Results are very noisy. Any suggestion on how to remove them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to do when faced with performance problems is to measure what is happening so you spend your time wisely optimising the critical parts. Regardless of the remainder of my answer, please measure the capture time and processing time. You can measure the capture time by commenting out the processing. You can measure the processing time by commenting out the capturing and just working on a static, representative frame repeatedly.

If your code runs at 30fps without processing, we could deduce that the acquisition probably takes 33ms - though you should measure it.

If the code runs at 5fps with processing, that means 200ms per frame, so we could deduce that the processing requires 167ms, i.e. 200ms - 33ms.

So, your best bet is either:

- find an equivalent algorithm that is as effective and faster, or,
- try to use multiprocessing to send the frames round-robin to each of, say, 4 CPU cores, so you would hopefully get a de-noised frame back every 42ms (167/4), That means you could hope to approach 20-25 fps.

Further, you should consider providing an **actual** image rather than a screen-grab of your combined results so that folk can run tests on representative data and even just know the size of your image. Actual images of your processed data would also be useful to assess noise-reduction performance. Its is also better if you include the `import` statements so folks know which modules you are using.

Comment: I will try out the measurements thank you for your input.